# How to Add Items From One ListView to Another

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am trying to parse the data in the first column of one ListView called `raw` and then if the data is correct, add that item to a second ListView called `result`.

However, when I go to run my program I get 
the error:

> "Cannot add or insert the item 'Collected' in more than one place.".

**My Code**

```
ListView result = new ListView();
for (int i = 0; i < raw.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (raw.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text.ToUpper() == "COLLECTED")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("confirm");
        result.Items.Add(raw.Items[i]); // generating erros
    }
}
printUsingLView(result);
```

Comment: Either remove it first (to move) or (to copy) create a new item, copying the data of the other , raw one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clone original item:

```
result.Items.Add((ListViewItem)raw.Items[i].Clone());
```

or, if you want to make some adjustments

```
ListViewItem newItem = new ListViewItem();
newItem.Text = raw.Items[i].Text;
//enter other properties here and then add it to new listView
result.Items.Add(newItem);
```